# How to save uploaded file in folder using HTML5, javasctipt/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to save uploaded files in my folder under same project directory or anywhere in machine. but i didn't got anything how to save using just **javascript or jquery**.
**HTML Code**

```
 <input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

**JS code is here**

```
 $('#myFile').on('change', function () {
            var filePath = $(this).val();
            console.log(filePath);
        });
```

Also, i'm not getting file uploaded path.
Please help me soon.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use server side to save upload file and you need to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

to get file name this use code

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById('yourIdHere').value;
if (fullPath) {
    var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
    if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(1);
    }
alert(filename);
}
```